# HashSet vs HashedSet (Iesi): strange behavior

Tags: c#, nhibernate, readonly-collection, iesi-collections

Today I was testing a couple of things on my domain model and I have realized the behavior wasn't what I expected.

I have tried to isolate the problem creating a simple `Customers-Orders` model.

This is my mapping.

**Customer:**

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" name="NHVariousTests.Domain.Customer, NHVariousTests" table="Customers">
    <id name="Code" type="System.Guid">
        <column name="CustomerCode" />
        <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    <version name="Version" type="System.Int32" unsaved-value="0" access="backfield"">
        <column name="Version" not-null="true" />
    </version>
    <property name="Description" type="AnsiString">
          <column name="Description" not-null="false" />
    </property>   
    <set name="Orders" access="field.pascalcase-underscore" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true" lazy="true">
        <key column="CustomerCode" />
        <one-to-many class="NHVariousTests.Domain.Order, NHVariousTests" />
    </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Order:**

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" name="NHVariousTests.Domain.Order, NHVariousTests" table="Orders">
    <id name="Code" type="System.Guid">
        <column name="OrderCode" />
        <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    <version name="Version" type="System.Int32" unsaved-value="0" access="backfield">
        <column name="Version" not-null="true" />
    </version>
    <property name="Description" type="AnsiString">
        <column name="Description" not-null="false" />
    </property>   
    <many-to-one class="NHVariousTests.Domain.Customer, NHVariousTests" name="Customer">
        <column name="CustomerCode" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My `Order` class is very simple:

```
public class Order : EntityGuid
{
    public Order()
    {
    }

    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my `Customer` class:

```
public class Customer : EntityGuid
{
    public Customer()
    {
        this._Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
    }

    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    #region Orders

    private readonly ICollection<Order> _Orders = null;

    public virtual ReadOnlyCollection<Order> Orders
    {
        get { return (new List<Order>(_Orders).AsReadOnly()); }
    }

    public virtual bool AddOrder(Order order)
    {
        if ((order != null) && (!this._Orders.Contains(order)))
        {
            order.Customer = this;
            this._Orders.Add(order);
            return (true);
        }
        return (false);
    }

    public virtual bool RemoveOrder(Order order)
    {
        if ((order != null) && (this._Orders.Contains(order)))
        {
            this._Orders.Remove(order);
            order.Customer = null;
            return (true);
        }
        return (false);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

in this first example I am using a private `ICollection<Order>` which is created as a `HashSet<Order>`.

If I run this code:

```
using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var customer = new Domain.Customer() { Description = "ACME Ltd" };

        var order = new Domain.Order() { Description = "Coffee" };
        customer.AddOrder(order);

        order = new Domain.Order() { Description = "Milk" };
        customer.AddOrder(order);

        session.Save(customer);

        tx.Commit();
    }
}
```

I can see the `INSERT` of the customer and the two `INSERT` for the orders but I've got an `UPDATE` for the customer, as well.

[image]

If I change my `Customer` class switching to **Iesi** collections:

```
public class Customer : EntityGuid
{
    public Customer()
    {
        this._Orders = new Iesi.Collections.Generic.HashedSet<Order>();
    }

    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    #region Orders

    private readonly ICollection<Order> _Orders = null;

    public virtual ReadOnlyCollection<Order> Orders
    {
        get { return (new List<Order>(_Orders).AsReadOnly()); }
    }

    public virtual bool AddOrder(Order order)
    {
        if ((order != null) && (!this._Orders.Contains(order)))
        {
            order.Customer = this;
            this._Orders.Add(order);
            return (true);
        }
        return (false);
    }

    public virtual bool RemoveOrder(Order order)
    {
        if ((order != null) && (this._Orders.Contains(order)))
        {
            this._Orders.Remove(order);
            order.Customer = null;
            return (true);
        }
        return (false);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I have got the expected behavior:

[image]

This is my `EntityGuid` class:

```
public abstract class EntityGuid : EntityWithTypedId<Guid>, IAuditedEntity
{
    public EntityGuid()
    {
        this.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        this.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        this.CreatedBy = "";
        this.UpdatedBy = "";
    }

    public virtual DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string UpdatedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual int Version { get; private set; }

    public virtual bool IsTransient()
    {
        return (EntityWithTypedId<Guid>.Equals(this.Code, default(Guid)));
    }

    public virtual bool IsTransient(EntityWithTypedId<Guid> obj)
    {
        return obj != null && Equals(obj.Code, default(Guid));
    }

}
```

Is there anyone who can help me to try and understand what's happening?

Regards.

**If someone is really interested to have a look at the code. I've cleaned everything and make it as simple as possible. Can be downloaded [here](https://skydrive.live.com/embed?cid=669ADF1AF64DF389&resid=669ADF1AF64DF389!236&authkey=AMW35O2P4XrsF5Y) (NH_CollectionProblems).**

*I am using NHibernate 3.3.2.4000*

Comment: Set dynamic-update="true" in the Customer mapping so that you can see what is being updated. I would also try changing the Orders return type to `IEnumerable<Order>`.

Comment: Thanks Jamie. It seems that the only thing that is being updated is the Version. If I use IEnumerable<Order> same thing happens.

Comment: Try removing the unnecessary collection initializer. that is do not set _Orders = null. How is the Version assigned?

Comment: Jamie: I've added my abstract class EntityGuid and have removed the initializer so that my member looks like this: `private ICollection<Order> _Orders = new HashSet<Order>();` but still the same problem.

Comment: Jamie: Surely has got something to do with the Version cause if I remove it everything works fine.

Comment: If you look at the mapping and the `abstract class EntityGuid` you will see. It's really weird. I've updated my question. Now the 2 classes are similar. If I only change the inizialization of the collection from `HashSet` to `Iesi.Collections.Generic.HashedSet` and everything works fine.

Comment: Jamie: I've attached a simple project to my question, just in case you want to have a look at my implementation. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you're expecting is wrong, you should expect that modifying a collection on a versioned entity will update the version. This behavior is described in [the documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-mapping) for mapping a collection which also describes how to disable it:

> optimistic-lock (optional - defaults to true): Species that changes to the state of the collection results in increment of the owning entity's version. (For one to many associations, it is often reasonable to disable this setting.)

I did pull down the project and verified that changing this setting toggled the update being issued: false = no update, true (default) = update. However, I could not get the expected behavior using the Iesi HashedSet. I think it's a bug but I don't have more time to work on it now.

Answer (score 1):

Either...

- Wait for NH 4.0 (which targets .net 4.0 where BCL's ISet is available). An alpha release will be available soon.
- Use https://bitbucket.org/jfromaniello/nhibernate.setfornet4. Available on nuget, http://nuget.org/packages/NHibernate.SetForNet4.